# Prevent background from scrolling when using keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield

I would like to have background scroll to focus the Textfield, but have the background image maintain it's position/aspect ratio.

What I have tried:

- Wrapped my Scaffold in a Container with a BoxDecoration containing the background image
- Wrapped my Scaffold with a stack, which included the image as the background
- Disabled resizeToAvoidBottomInset in my Scaffold

Using the first and third option listed:

```
class LoginPage extends BasePage {
  LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key, configTypes: [ConfigurationType.login]);
  
  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends BaseState<LoginPage> with BasicPage {
  @override
  Widget body() {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: ExactAssetImage(Assets.bgLogin), // Assets is constant to filepath
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // To see background image
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ... // Contains textfield/other UI elements
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is a demo of the background scrolling:

[image: Background-scrolling.gif]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return the Scaffold with your Container inside it.
You are preventing the image to scroll on the Scaffold but not the scrolling of the parent Countainer.

```
class _LoginPageState extends BaseState<LoginPage> with BasicPage {
  @override
  Widget body() {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // To see background image
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: ExactAssetImage(Assets.bgLogin), // Assets is constant to filepath
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: ... // Contains textfield/other UI elements
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve my issue.

Comment: What it the code of the home page (where the LoginPage is used)?

Comment: LoginPage is the entire page, I navigate to it using nav 2.0. Minus the child body of the scaffold, app bar, and image file, everything is included.